# pass a list of my model to Transaction in ArangoDB-NET

Tags: c#, arangodb

I simply worked with Transaction in [ArnagoDB_NET](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET) when I work with one item of my model. but I have a problem when I want to pass a list of my model.

```
var transactionResult= Context.Transaction.WriteCollection("User").Execute<Dictionary<string, object>>(
  string.Format(@" 
    function () {{ 
       var db = require('internal');
      if(!db.User.exists('{0}')) 
           db.User.save( {{ _key:'{0}', UserAppState:1 }});
         }}
      // and other actions
       return {{ 'Executed': true }};
    }}", myModel.userId))
```

above example fine worked, but when I want to pass a list of my model, how can I iterate them into string(or ArangoDB script)?

for example:

```
string.Format(@" 
    function () {{ 
       var db = require('internal');
       for (i = 0; i < {0}.count; i++){{       // I know didn't work this block code!
        if(!db.User.exists('{i.key}'))
           db.User.save( {{ _key: ""'i.key'"", UserAppState:1 }});
           // and other actions
        }}
       return {{ 'Executed': true }};
    }}", lstMyModels);
```

can any one help me?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this would be possible given your example, since you are combining C# string interpolated object with ArangoDB transaction functionality which doesn't work together just by combining them into single query.

Your first example works because it's using primitive value which you pass into the string, however in the second example you want to pass list of objects and iterate through them using cycle that is not in any way connected to the list itself. This line

```
for (i = 0; i < {0}.count; i++) {
```

won't work because `lstMyModels` is a C# list object and you would actually end up with a string interpolated like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object].count; i++) {
```

which makes no sense to the ArangoDB which needs to execute the transaction. Moreover the `i` variable is a simple number serving as current cycle iteration index therefore calling `i.key` is also wrong.

Instead of complicated string interpolation you should try to use [transaction parameter passing](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Transactions/Passing.html) which is [supported by the ArangoDB-NET](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET/blob/master/docs/TransactionOperations.md#execute-transaction) driver.

**EDIT:**

Let's say you have object like this:

```
public class TransactionEntity
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can pass it as transaction parameter for example like this:

```
var transactionData = new List<TransactionEntity>
{
    new TransactionEntity
    {
        Foo = "string1"
    },
    new TransactionEntity
    {
        Foo = "string2"
    },
    new TransactionEntity
    {
        Foo = "string3"
    }
};

var transactionResult = db.Transaction
    .WriteCollection("myCollection")
    .Param("data", transactionData)
    .Execute<List<TransactionEntity>>(@"
    function (params) { 
        var db = require('internal').db;

        for (var i = 0; i < params.data.length; i++) {
            db.myCollection.save(params.data[i]);
        }

        return db._query('FOR doc IN myCollection SORT TO_NUMBER(doc._key) RETURN doc').toArray();
    }
    ");
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. I knew your comment about interpolate c# list object and string... but I guess it's impossible even with [transaction parameter passing](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Transactions/Passing.html), which supported in ArangoDB-NET... can you implement my challenge with that? how to iterate my list using this driver?

Comment: @KorekiXeri Can you provide me the structure of your object which you want to be passed as transaction parameter?

Comment: in a simple use case, my object is: Contact(edge Coll)[properties: From , To , UserName,  etc], that pass as a List<Contact> to transaction. this list must be persist as a transaction into ArangoDB.

Comment: @KorekiXeri I'm going to implement into the driver the possibility to pass list of objects as transaction parameter since this option is currently not supported.

Comment: @KorekiXeri I added example to the answer how you can pass list of objects with current driver version and work with the list inside the transaction.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's worked... with this way I have a problem when working with edges in C#: I used **[AliasField]** for mapping my edge attribute(_from , _to). and when passing my model, it's didn't know my mapping, and I got this error: _"edge attribute missing or invalid"_... exists any solution for this challenge?

Comment: @KorekiXeri Please open an issue on github repo regarding this with specific example so that I can reproduce it. Thanks.